# using unlinkAsync file deleted and throws Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Mern Stack\udyog-asha\backend\public\cs.word.pdf'

Tags: express, multer, delete-file, drive

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + Date.now() + file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage }).array("file", 18);   
 var i = 0;
                    while (i < 18) {
                      if (req.files[i] != undefined) {
                        console.log("MY" + i);
                        const filePath_1 = path.join(
                          __dirname,
                          `../public/${req.files[i].filename}`
                        );
                        console.log(response_2);
                        const response_file_1 = await drive.files.create({
                          requestBody: {
                            parents: [response_2.data.id],
                            name: req.files[i].filename, //This can be name of your choice
                            mimeType: "application/pdf",
                          },
                          media: {
                            mimeType: "application/pdf",
                            body: fs.createReadStream(filePath_1),
                          },
                        })
                        unlinkAsync(req.files[i].path);
                      }
                      i++;
                    }
```

I have done all the necessary conditions of initializing milter and unlinkAsync. Everything is working fine but when it comes to delete the file from multer storage, file got deleted but throws the error No such file directory exist.
Error in deleting the file, I don't know what to do please somebody help.
here is the full error:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Mern Stack\udyog-asha\backend\public\cs.word.pdf'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:132:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:154:23) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'E:\\Mern Stack\\udyog-asha\\backend\\public\\cs.word.pdf'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason behind of throwing the error is because **multer never save duplicate files** and **I was uploading multiple duplicate files**.. before it can read the file and save it to drive files get deleted and it throws err.

So the solution is change the name. for example **add timestamp** so that there will be no error.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + Date.now() + file.originalname);
  },
});
```

**file.fieldname + Date.now() + file.originalname**  , this is the important line.